# Converting python long input to pseudo code

Tags: python, pseudocode

```
example = example + str(i + 1) + ": " + input("Example: ") + "\n"
```

the code above is giving me trouble converting it to pseudo code. I have tried
doing something like :
take user input for the example, add the example number at the start. Store it in a string on separate lines.

What i tried doesn't look right and sitting around for a few minutes i have concluded that i need some help.

Comment: What do you mean by convert to pseudo code? You mean explain what that line does in words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `example = ""` and you are looping over some `i` value, and rewriting like so

```
example += str(i + 1) + ": " + input("Example: ") + "\n"
```

You can say "append a new line starting with the next number in the sequence followed by user input"

In terms of pseudo code, I don't really see what needs converted. That one line is pretty concise.